# If $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, then a < b iff $ a \leq b + \frac{1}{n}$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

The question also asks to show that $a<b$ iff $a \leq b - \frac{1}{n}$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$. My proof (in the forward direction) starts off like this:

> $a \leq b$ can be rewritten as $0 \leq b-a$. By Archimedean property, $ \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $ 1 \leq n(b-a)$. Then we have that $\frac {1}{n} \leq b-a$. Thus, $\frac{1}{n} + a \leq b$.

However, this is not the same as $ a \leq b + \frac{1}{n}$. I then tried an alternative appraoch:

> $a \leq b \implies -a \geq -b \implies -a + b \geq 0$. By Archimedean, $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $ n(-a+b)\geq 1 \implies -a+b \geq \frac{1}{n} \implies b \geq \frac{1}{n} + a$

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could point out where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Do you want to show that $a\leq b + 1/n$ for all $n$?

Comment: Yes! Sorry, I should have been more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, mind a slight inaccuracy in the question: You need to allow for the possibility that $a=b$, so the "if" half of the "iff" must be $a\leq b$, not a strict inequality.

For the forward direction, you're overthinking: If $a\leq b$, and certainly $1/n > 0$, then ...

For the converse, suppose $a\leq b+\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Then you know that $a-b\leq \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n$. Hence $(a-b)n\leq 1$ for all $n$. But now you know the Archimedean principle, so what does that force $a-b$ to be?

Comment: For the forward, if $a \leq b$, then we gave that $ \frac{1}{n} \leq b-a$. If we assume $\frac{1}{n}>0$, then we have 0 < 1/n $ \leq $ b-a. Which gives $a+\frac{1}{n} \leq b$? 

As for the converse, this implies (a-b) $\leq$ 0 and $a \leq b$?

Comment: @Nikitau Still thinking too hard! $a\leq b\leq b+ \cdots$

Comment: Oh my god I am really really sorry and really embarrassed. I get it now. If $a \leq b$ then if $ b \ neq b + 1/n$ then $a \leq b + 1/n$.

Comment: @Nikitau Glad you understand. No worries, we've all been there :)

Answer (score 2):

Start with the assumption that $a\leq b+1/n$ for all $n$. We want to show $a\leq b$. Assume if possible that $a>b$. Then $a-b>0$. So, $a-b>1/n$ for some n. This contradicts what we started with. So this proves $a\leq b$